# How is the compiler tricked into providing a pointer to the enclosing class?

Tags: c++, class, pointers, pointer-arithmetic, field-accessors

I was reading an [article](http://www.nanoant.com/c++/cpp-field-accessors-cure-for-public-field-fobia) on how C++ does not have field accessors as part of the language.

At the end of the post, the author gives a macro based solution that emulates field accessors for classes:

```
// a little trick to fool compiler we are not accessing NULL pointer here
#define property_offset(type, name) \
  (((char*)&((type*)(0xffff))->name) - (char*)(0xffff))

#define property_parent(type, name) \
  ((type*)((char*)(this) - property_offset(type, name)))

// macro defining property
#define property(type, name, parent)                                         \
  struct name##_property {                                                   \
    operator type() { return property_parent(parent, name)->get_##name(); }  \
    void operator=(type v) { property_parent(parent, name)->set_##name(v); } \
                                                                             \
   private:                                                                  \
    char zero[0];                                                            \
  } name

// our main class
class Node {

  /* visitCount will act as a field accessor */
  property(int, visitCount, Node);
};
```

When I run this through the preprocessor, I get:

```
class Node {

  struct visitCount_property {
    operator int() { return ((Node*)((char*)(this) - (((char*)&((Node*)(0xffff))->visitCount) - (char*)(0xffff))))->get_visitCount(); }
    void operator=(int v) { ((Node*)((char*)(this) - (((char*)&((Node*)(0xffff))->visitCount) - (char*)(0xffff))))->set_visitCount(v); }    
    private: char zero[0];
    } visitCount;
};
```

The idea being that I would have also added my own implementations of:

```
int get_visitCount();
void set_visitCount(int v);
```

And it would look as if `visitCount` was being directly accessed.
However, the functions would actually be called behind the scenes:

```
Node n;
n.visitCount = 1;     //actually calls set method
cout << n.VisitCount; //actually calls get method
```

**I'd like to know more about this trick of accessing the enclosing class:**

```
((Node*)((char*)(this) - (((char*)&((Node*)(0xffff))
```

What is the relevance of `0xffff`?
In decimal that is:  `65535`.

**How does this trick the compiler to accessing the class that encloses the visitCount class?**

I also see that this does not work on MSVC, so I was wondering if there was a standard way of accomplishing what this hack is doing.

Comment: Well his proposed hack is quite ugly compared to a trick to replace the assignements with function calls. He says it doesn't work because the strict standard implementation doesn't allow a structure taking 0 bytes so the pointer address trick doesn't work.

Comment: @ShafikYaghmour in the link it's explicitely stated that `offsetof` doesn't work (see caveats in the link)

Comment: @meneldal it is using a very similar trick at is core with all the same issues which make offsetof not portable. There are a number of SO questions that cover this is some detail.

Comment: That implementation's a disgusting mess (0 length arrays are non-Standard, macro hackery etc., the casting and `0xffff`); I'd suggest considering the code at the end of [this document](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2004/n1615.pdf) instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no relevance of `0xffff`. It's just some number. It could be zero (and in fact would be easier if it were). Let's break this up into pieces and rewrite `0xffff` to be `addr`:

```
(((char*)&((type*)(addr))->name) - (char*)(addr))
```

`(type*)(addr)` just gives us some `type*` that starts at `addr`. It's a `reinterpret_cast`. So let's call that `obj`:

```
 (((char*)&obj->name) - (char*)(addr))
```

We can even replace the second `addr` with `obj` - it's the wrong type, but we're casting anyway, and it adds clarity to what's going on:

```
 (((char*)&obj->name) - (char*)(obj))
```

`&obj->name` just gives us a pointer to that particular member, so let's call that `mem_ptr`

```
((char*)mem_ptr) - (char*)(obj)
```

Now it's clear - we're taking the address of the member (as a `char*`) and subtracting the address of the parent object (as a `char*`). We used `0xffff` just to have the same initial address in both places.

Note that the C++ standard also defines a macro for this directly. It's called [`offsetof`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/offsetof). With the caveat "If *type* is not a standard-layout class (Clause 9), the results are undefined."

Comment: I believe that if you used zero the compiler would see it and give you some big warning because it's equal to `NULL`

Comment: @meneldal No it wouldn't.

Comment: I guess I hadn't actually tried.  Using zero in place of 0xffff seems to work fine on g++.